# Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent error using "sqlSave"

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I'm trying to use sqlSave command to import R dataframe into SQL database. Below is my code

```
> head(final_series)
   Price       Time        FactorID CountryID      id
1  5.363334e+01 1980-01-01        1         1       1
2  5.143333e+01 1980-04-01        1         1   16384
3  5.060000e+01 1980-07-01        1         1   32767
4  5.250000e+01 1980-10-01        1         1   49150
5  5.266667e+01 1981-01-01        1         1   65533
6  5.280000e+01 1981-04-01        1         1   81916

> sqlSave(dbhandle, final_series, tablename = "db_time_price", varTypes = c(id="uniqueidentifier", FactorID= "float", CountryID="float", Time="date", Price="float"), append=TRUE, verbose = T, fast = F)
```

But I got the following error:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: sqlSave is a function of which R package?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the table already exists? If the table already exists but with a different dimension you would see this error.